# How to convert a jar file to an executable with MySQL in it?

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans, executable-jar

I have a java application which uses MySQL as its database. In order to deliver the project, I need to convert it to an executable with MySQL included. I have tried exe4j but it doesn't allow to include the database. Please advice. The project is done in Netbeans.

Comment: You have to use a third party application to install your database. I would vote for [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's not being actively developed any longer due to low demand, you can have a look at the [MySQL-Connector/MXJ](http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-mxj/) package that's meant for "embedding" your MySQL-database into your application - I recon' it still should be able to do the trick.

But to be honest, the most future-proof solution would be to switch out your database with another option, preferably an **in memory** database such as [H2database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) or [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html).